# How can I reference cursor item in a for loop or while loop?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I'm attempting to loop through database values creating tabs.  I have setup a method called createTab which accepts a Long value and a String value.  It's working with static data, but I'm struggling to understand how to loop through SQLite database records.

Here is my failed attempt (replace [lessthan] with less than symbol):

```java
for (int i = 0; i [lessthan] mCursor.getCount(); i++)
{
 createTab(
  mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")),
  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("category")));
}
```

You probably don't need the LogCat to know what I did wrong in the code above, but just in case...

```
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:172)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:99)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at com.toBuy.Main.createTabs(Main.java:51)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at com.toBuy.Main.onCreate(Main.java:38)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
08-27 21:28:18.268: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(232):     ... 11 more
08-27 21:28:18.278: INFO/Process(54): Sending signal. PID: 232 SIG: 3
08-27 21:28:18.278: INFO/dalvikvm(232): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
08-27 21:28:18.338: INFO/dalvikvm(232): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
08-27 21:28:18.508: INFO/ARMAssembler(54): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 27 ipp] (41 ins) at [0x285a68:0x285b0c] in 713498 ns
08-27 21:28:18.518: INFO/ARMAssembler(54): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00001001_00000000 [ 64 ipp] (84 ins) at [0x285b10:0x285c60] in 1897448 ns
08-27 21:28:28.086: WARN/ActivityManager(54): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
08-27 21:28:28.097: WARN/ActivityManager(54): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{4390bf70 com.toBuy/.Main}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to position the cursor before you can call `getLong` or `getString`.  After you issue a query, the `Cursor` is positioned just before the first row, so you should call `moveToNext` in your loop.  Something like:

```
int size = mCursor.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

    // Position the cursor
    mCursor.moveToNext();

    // Fetch your data values
    long id = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    String cat = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("category"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What I'm struggling with at this point is referencing the columns within the cursor.

How would the // Fetch your data values look for a Long columns (_id) and a String columns (category)?

Comment: You'd still access the column values exactly like you're doing in your sample.  The Cursor object contains a pointer to the row in the database that it's currently pointing at, and your sample code just needed to position it before calling any get* methods.  If that doesn't fix your problem, I'd pull the database off of the device (or emulator) and double check the schema.

Answer (score 1):

In my code I have get value from SQLite database and store that value in array of object of model Class (FriendData is my model class) using Cursor.

```
   Cursor cursor = friendAdapter.fetchData(); //call method for fetch data from databse and fetched data is stored into cursor
    int cursorSize = cursor.getCount();

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         FriendData[] friendData=new FriendData[cursorSize];  //create array of objects as size of cursor

            for (int i = 0; i < cursorSize; i++) {
                   friendData[i]=new FriendData();

                  /*store fetched data in some variables. In my code I have store value of cursor in friendName String variable*/
                  friendName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FriendAdapter.FRIEND_NM));

                 /* set friendName variable value in array of object*/
                 friendData[i].setFriendName(friendName);

              cursor.moveToNext();  //move cursor for pointing to next fetched record
           }
     }
```

First I have Check Condition for Cursor is it null and move Cursor Object for pointing to First record which are fetched. Then I have compute size of cursor using method getCount(). After that for loop is used to store all data in array of object and at the end cursor is pointing to next record which are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for loop:

```
   for(mCursor.moveToFirst();!mCursor.isAfterLast();mCursor.moveToNext()){
        createTab(
  mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")),
  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("category")));    
        }
```

Although , while loop would be much simpler:

```
while (mCursor.moveToNext()) { createTab(
  mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")),
  mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("category")));
```

}

In both cases, you dont need to set the cursor's starting position manually.